# How to fix the stuck after logging in with Mikrotik API script?

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, mikrotik

I'm having my thesis right now about Mikrotik scripting. I try the API on the Mikrotik website but I can't make any query into Mikrotik after my the login method on the Mikrotik router sends the !done message. It seems the script stuck after logging in. I have tried some suggestion on previous questions and even combined my script with another API script but it still stucks. How to fix this?
Thanks.

This is my main code : (Basicly this code is same with the Mikrotik API)

```py
def main():
    user = "admin"
    passw = ""

    #use default username and password if not specified
    if len(sys.argv) == 4:
        user = sys.argv[2]
        passw = sys.argv[3]

    elif len(sys.argv) == 3:
        user = sys.argv[2]

    s = None
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(sys.argv[1], "8728", socket.AF_UNSPEC, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
        af, socktype, proto, canonname, sa = res
        try:
            s = socket.socket(af, socktype, proto)
        except (socket.error):
            s = None
            continue
        try:
            s.connect(sa)
        except (socket.error):
            s.close()
            s = None
            continue
        break
    if s is None:
        print ('could not open socket')
        sys.exit(1)

    mikrotik = Mikrotik(s)
    mikrotik.login(user, passw)

    inputsentence = []


    while 1:
        r = select.select([s, sys.stdin], [], [], None)
        #r = select.select(s, [], [], 0.0)
        if s in r[0]:
            x = mikrotik.readSentence() # something to read in socket, read sentence

        if sys.stdin in r[0]: 
            l = sys.stdin.readline() # read line from input and strip off newline
            l = l[:-1]

            # if empty line, send sentence and start with new
            # otherwise append to input sentence
            if l == '':
                mikrotik.writeSentence(inputsentence)
                inputsentence = []
            else:
                inputsentence.append(l)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I expect the script will allow me to pass query into my Mikrotik router but unfortunately, the script stops after giving !done message and returning this error message.

```py
in main function 
r = select.select([s, sys.stdin], [], [], None)
OSError: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket
```

Comment: Your code looks fine but did you checked log of mikrotik device? May be there is something wrong with login attempt.

Comment: @viilpe I have checked it and the log says that my account only logged in and logged out through API at the same time. I saw the earlier post that mikrotik API had bug. The bug is shown on the error message. The post suggested that we should change the command "select.select([s, sys.stdin], [], [], None)" into "select.select(s, [], [], 0.0)" but that command gives me another error.

Comment: I posted my variant of module as an answer. It works well for me so try it.

Comment: @viilpe . Thanks man. I think your code works well but it is still giving me the same error. I guess the problem is with my Windows OS which can't use the command "r = select.select([s, sys.stdin], [], [], None)". I haven't tried on Linux OS though. Is there any chance to change that command so the Windows OS won't give that error message again?

Comment: You said nothing about versions of your software. May be you have outdated RouterOS or Python. My setup: Python 7.3.2, Windows 7 x64 (with latest updates), RouterOS 6.43.2. You should try on another Windows PC or on Virtual PC at least.

Comment: @viilpe Thanks for your help. I have figured it out. I got reference from another site and site document. Both are telling about this, "File objects on Windows are not acceptable, but sockets are. On Windows, the underlying select() function is provided by the WinSock library, and does not handle file descriptors that don’t originate from WinSock." I change sys.stdin in your previous main code and now I can logged in and send my command into my mikrotik.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code which I'm correcting in main code. And this code will ONLY WORKS on Windows only.. 
This will do on Windows because Windows cannot accept file objects or handle file descriptors which aren't from its original WinSock library.

```py
while 1:
        r = select.select([s], [], [], 1)[0]
        import msvcrt
        if msvcrt.kbhit(): r.append(sys.stdin)
        if s in r:
            # something to read in socket, read sentence
            x = apiros.readSentence()

        if sys.stdin in r:
            # read line from input and strip off newline
            l = sys.stdin.readline()
            l = l[:-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is my slightly mofidied version of same python module. It works well in python 3+ and RouterOS 6.3+

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: latin-1 -*-
import sys, time, binascii, socket, select
import hashlib

class ApiRos:
    "Routeros api"
    def __init__(self, sk, silent:bool=False):
        self.sk = sk
        self.currenttag = 0
        self.silent = silent

    def login(self, username, pwd):
        for repl, attrs in self.talk(["/login", "=name=" + username,
                                      "=password=" + pwd]):
          if repl == '!trap':
            return False
          elif '=ret' in attrs.keys():
        #for repl, attrs in self.talk(["/login"]):
            chal = binascii.unhexlify((attrs['=ret']).encode(sys.stdout.encoding))
            md = hashlib.md5()
            md.update(b'\x00')
            md.update(pwd.encode(sys.stdout.encoding))
            md.update(chal)
            for repl2, attrs2 in self.talk(["/login", "=name=" + username,
                   "=response=00" + binascii.hexlify(md.digest()).decode(sys.stdout.encoding) ]):
              if repl2 == '!trap':
                return False
        return True

    def talk(self, words):
        if self.writeSentence(words) == 0: return
        r = []
        while 1:
            i = self.readSentence();
            if len(i) == 0: continue
            reply = i[0]
            attrs = {}
            for w in i[1:]:
                j = w.find('=', 1)
                if (j == -1):
                    attrs[w] = ''
                else:
                    attrs[w[:j]] = w[j+1:]
            r.append((reply, attrs))
            if reply == '!done': return r

    def writeSentence(self, words):
        ret = 0
        for w in words:
            self.writeWord(w)
            ret += 1
        self.writeWord('')
        return ret

    def readSentence(self):
        r = []
        while 1:
            w = self.readWord()
            if w == '': return r
            r.append(w)

    def writeWord(self, w):
        if not self.silent: print(("<<< " + w))
        self.writeLen(len(w))
        self.writeStr(w)

    def readWord(self):
        ret = self.readStr(self.readLen())
        if not self.silent: print((">>> " + ret))
        return ret

    def writeLen(self, l):
        if l < 0x80:
            self.writeByte((l).to_bytes(1, sys.byteorder))
        elif l < 0x4000:
            l |= 0x8000
            tmp = (l >> 8) & 0xFF
            self.writeByte(((l >> 8) & 0xFF).to_bytes(1, sys.byteorder))
            self.writeByte((l & 0xFF).to_bytes(1, sys.byteorder))
        elif l < 0x200000:
            l |= 0xC00000
            self.writeByte(((l >> 16) & 0xFF).to_bytes(1, sys.byteorder))
            self.writeByte(((l >> 8) & 0xFF).to_bytes(1, sys.byteorder))
            self.writeByte((l & 0xFF).to_bytes(1, sys.byteorder))
        elif l < 0x10000000:
            l |= 0xE0000000
            self.writeByte(((l >> 24) & 0xFF).to_bytes(1, sys.byteorder))
            self.writeByte(((l >> 16) & 0xFF).to_bytes(1, sys.byteorder))
            self.writeByte(((l >> 8) & 0xFF).to_bytes(1, sys.byteorder))
            self.writeByte((l & 0xFF).to_bytes(1, sys.byteorder))
        else:
            self.writeByte((0xF0).to_bytes(1, sys.byteorder))
            self.writeByte(((l >> 24) & 0xFF).to_bytes(1, sys.byteorder))
            self.writeByte(((l >> 16) & 0xFF).to_bytes(1, sys.byteorder))
            self.writeByte(((l >> 8) & 0xFF).to_bytes(1, sys.byteorder))
            self.writeByte((l & 0xFF).to_bytes(1, sys.byteorder))

    def readLen(self):
        c = ord(self.readStr(1))
        # print (">rl> %i" % c)
        if (c & 0x80) == 0x00:
            pass
        elif (c & 0xC0) == 0x80:
            c &= ~0xC0
            c <<= 8
            c += ord(self.readStr(1))
        elif (c & 0xE0) == 0xC0:
            c &= ~0xE0
            c <<= 8
            c += ord(self.readStr(1))
            c <<= 8
            c += ord(self.readStr(1))
        elif (c & 0xF0) == 0xE0:
            c &= ~0xF0
            c <<= 8
            c += ord(self.readStr(1))
            c <<= 8
            c += ord(self.readStr(1))
            c <<= 8
            c += ord(self.readStr(1))
        elif (c & 0xF8) == 0xF0:
            c = ord(self.readStr(1))
            c <<= 8
            c += ord(self.readStr(1))
            c <<= 8
            c += ord(self.readStr(1))
            c <<= 8
            c += ord(self.readStr(1))
        return c

    def writeStr(self, str):
        n = 0;
        while n < len(str):
            r = self.sk.send(bytes(str[n:], 'UTF-8'))
            if r == 0: raise RuntimeError("connection closed by remote end")
            n += r

    def writeByte(self, str):
        n = 0;
        while n < len(str):
            r = self.sk.send(str[n:])
            if r == 0: raise RuntimeError("connection closed by remote end")
            n += r

    def readStr(self, length):
        ret = ''
        # print ("length: %i" % length)
        while len(ret) < length:
            s = self.sk.recv(length - len(ret))
            if s == b'': raise RuntimeError("connection closed by remote end")
            # print (b">>>" + s)
            # atgriezt kaa byte ja nav ascii chars
            if s >= (128).to_bytes(1, "big") :
               return s
            # print((">>> " + s.decode(sys.stdout.encoding, 'ignore')))
            ret += s.decode(sys.stdout.encoding, "replace")
        return ret

def main():
    s = None
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(sys.argv[1], "8728", socket.AF_UNSPEC, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
        af, socktype, proto, canonname, sa = res
        try:
             s = socket.socket(af, socktype, proto)
        except socket.error:
            s = None
            continue
        try:
            s.connect(sa)
        except socket.error:
            s.close()
            s = None
            continue
        break
    if s is None:
        print ('could not open socket')
        sys.exit(1)

    apiros = ApiRos(s);

    # use default username and pasword if not specified
    if len(sys.argv) == 4:
      if not apiros.login(sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3]):
        return
    elif len(sys.argv) == 3:
      if not apiros.login(sys.argv[2], ""):
        return
    else :
      if not apiros.login("admin", ""):
        return

    inputsentence = []

    while 1:
        r = select.select([s, sys.stdin], [], [], None)
        if s in r[0]:
            # something to read in socket, read sentence
            x = apiros.readSentence()

        if sys.stdin in r[0]:
            # read line from input and strip off newline
            l = sys.stdin.readline()
            l = l[:-1]

            # if empty line, send sentence and start with new
            # otherwise append to input sentence
            if l == '':
                apiros.writeSentence(inputsentence)
                inputsentence = []
            else:
                inputsentence.append(l)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```